# Counting for how many instances a bool property is true - C#

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have an IEnumerable of a certain object which has a bool property. I would like to count for how many objects this property is set to true in a compact (in terms of code lines) and readable way.

To demonstrate it, Iv'e create a class 'Obj' with a boolean property 'InnerProperty'. The static function 'CountInner' implements the defined logic above. How can I implement it in a more compactly?

```
public class Obj
{
    private bool InnerProperty { get; set; } = false;

    public static int CountInner(IEnumerable<Obj> list)
    {
        var count = 0;
        foreach (var l in list)
        {
            if (l.InnerProperty)
            {
                count++;
            }
        }
        return count;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You could use LINQ's [`Count`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx) which accepts a predicate ("a function to test each element for a condition."):

```
public static int CountInner(IEnumerable<Obj> list)
{
    return list.Count(x => x.InnerProperty);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Essentially the same as the other answers, using an expression bodied member :

```
public static int CountInner(IEnumerable<Obj> list) => list.Count(x => x.InnerProperty);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use Linq probably `System.Linq` like below. Morever, `InnerProperty` should be a field rather a property since for a `private` property setter won't make much sense

```
public static int CountInner(IEnumerable<Obj> list)
{
    var count = list.Where(l => l.InnerProperty).Count(); 
    return count;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do it in a much more easier way:

```
public class Obj
{
    private bool InnerProperty { get; set; } = false;

    public static int CountInner(IEnumerable<Obj> list)
    {
        return list.Count(b => b.InnerProperty);
    }
}
```

just use [Lambda Expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/lambda-expressions).